# Is there a shortcut to the Executioner's Chariot?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Seriously.  It's kind of ridiculous.  I'm assuming (hoping?) that there's some shortcut between the **Huntsman's Copse - Bridge Approach** bonfire and the fog wall leading to this boss.  The rope bridge is right above the bonfire, so it's not that big of a stretch, right?

Please tell me there's a way, or my playthrough might just end here.  Haha.  I don't know if I can keep going through them over and over in order to even try and figure *out* how to beat the Chariot.

Comment: Just kill them off one by one a few more times and they will start to disappear right? I am not at the part of the game so they may be special.

Comment: @Reafexus Nice point.  I think some mobs aren't subject to the spawn limit, but maybe you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a shortcut of any kind, unfortunately. Sorry. Confirmed in the Collector's Edition game guide.

As for the Chariot, it's really not that difficult of a fight relatively speaking. If you want some tips, see below.

> As soon as the fight starts, begin heading to the left. There are skeletons that will harass you, but don't worry about killing them. They will be resurrected by one of two necromancers. Basically, just push around the area as much as you can, taking time to duck into the small alcoves when you see the chariot coming. The chariot will either kill or knock down any skeletons that happen to be harassing you. Keep sprinting toward the first necromancer and kill it. Then clean up all the skeletons around you. Next sprint toward the second necromancer and and kill it, then clean up the skeletons. Once the two necros and all the skeletons are dead, you should see a switch across from you. Flip the switch and the fight will transition into a much more traditional style boss fight. Good luck and remember that horses don't like it when you stand right behind them.

Comment: Spoilers!  Haha.  I like trying to figure out how to beat the bosses on my own.  Thanks for the info, though.  I genuinely thought I was missing something.  Then again, shouldn't surprise me after having to fight the seven million stone giants on the way to the Dragonslayer.

Comment: Sorry about the spoilers. I worried about that as I was writing it.  My favorite trick for learning the bosses is to drop my white soap stone. Then you get to the see the fight with lower risk, often with somebody who has attempted the fight at least once before. Do the fight as a helper a time or two and they go super smooth after that.

Comment: That's actually an awesome idea.  Though to be honest, I haven't been super impressed with boss difficulty in Dark Souls 2 so far (having only fought The Last Giant and the Dragonrider, of course).  Their movesets were kind of stale and predictable.  I've found some normal mobs/setups more challenging than the actual bosses.

Comment: @Jeff You have not yet completed 8% of the bosses. They'll get plenty difficult.

Answer (score 5):

If you go from the third bonfire, there is a bit of a shortcut. But you will have to do a pretty fancy jump. It's surprisingly easy for how it looks.
What you do, is from the third bonfire, go to the left side of the bridge you lowered to get there. Stand on the very edge, so you can see the edge below. Run along the edge, and jump against the very edge of the wall. You will be pushed slightly to the side, but you will keep going straight, and land on the edge of the ledge below. Try to spam rolling to the left when you land, so that you don't accidentally fall of while turning or something.
The trees down there will not have loaded in yet, so don't be starteled when they suddenly appear

Answer (score 0):

Kill the two mages that res the skeletons then make your way to the last door on the right. From there fire off 1 arrow as he comes around the corner. If you keep firing right as you see the horses shadow you will eventually kill the executioner and the horses will fall in the pit making this one of the easiest bosses in dark souls. If you can't get past skeletons just wait for the chariot to pummel them then kill the mages.

Comment: That's by far the worst method to kill the executioner

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just avoid the skeletons and let the chariot kill them and rush the necromancers. Boss is pretty easy. Here is the vid: